# Why is the pandas dataframe converting integer to float datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file as

```
Wed Dec 04 11:30:04 GMT+05:30 2019,20,35.0,143455434,0
Wed Dec 04 11:30:13 GMT+05:30 2019,40,25.5,null,
```

I would like to load this in pandas and convert individual columns into my respective data types. 
This is how I do it

```
raw_df = pd.read_csv('raw.csv', dtype=str)
raw_df = raw_df.replace({'null':None, pd.np.nan: None})
```

This is my function to convert

```
def df_function(row):
    row['timestamp'] = parse(row['timestamp'])
    row['odometer'] = float(row['odometer']) + 1
    row['speed'] = float(row['speed'])

    if row['id'] is not None:
        row['id'] = str(row['id'])

    if row['error_code'] is not None:
        row['error_code'] = int(row['error_code'])

    return row
```

```
raw_df = raw_df.apply(df_function, axis=1)
```

When you print the data types of the columns you will find

```
timestamp     datetime64[ns, tzoffset(None, -19800)]
odometer                                     float64
speed                                        float64
id                                            object
error_code                                   float64
dtype: object
```

**error_code** is float64, though it should be int64, what is the issue here

Comment: Your `error_code` column must be having Null values, in that case `pandas` automatically converts it into `float` as `np.nan` datatype is considered as `float`

Comment: But I would like int to have none as lot of values are null and I would represent int to be none in pandas. How to do that?

Comment: Work around could be define a `error_code` for Null values and replace it in original dataframe

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support

Comment: I tried with the latest version of pandas and still the same issue

Comment: Have you read this? `The Integer NA support currently uses the capitalized dtype version, e.g. Int8 as compared to the traditional int8. This may be changed at a future date.` Try changing datatype of column to `Int8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in [`pandas` documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

> The Integer NA support currently uses the capitalized dtype version,
>   e.g. Int8 as compared to the traditional int8. This may be changed at
>   a future date

You need to change your column into `Int8`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"error_code":[1,2,5,np.nan]}) 
print(df.dtypes)

# error_code    float64
# dtype: object

df["error_code"] = df["error_code"].astype("Int8") 
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
error_code    Int8
dtype: object
```

Comment: In function you are processing row by row. Maybe you can skip that part in your function and write single line like `df["error_code"] = df["error_code"].astype("Int8")`

Comment: The custom function performs a lot of operation based on the config file ( I have not showed this in the custom function ). That is why I am using a custom function to convert the data types. If it is not possible, then I would be doing one more operation after calling the conversion function. An overhead but yes will work

Comment: This could be case of limitations of performing row by row opeartions or `df.apply`